# Vim - Neosnippet disable indentation

Tags: vim

Now I have this neosnippet and the output indents the lines in between the first and the last.

```
snippet doc
alias /..
    /**
     *
     * @package    ${1}
     * @author     Author Name <authorname@gmail.com>
     * @license    ${2:http://www.wtfpl.net/ Do What the Fuck You Want to Public License}
     * @version    Release: ${3:0.1.0}
     * @link       http://github.com/${4}
     * @since      Class available since Release ${5:0.1.0}
     */
${6:TARGET}
```

The output snippet ends up like this...

```
/**
    *
    * @package
    * @author     Author Name <authorname@gmail.com>
    * @license    http://www.wtfpl.net/ Do What the Fuck You Want to Public License
    * @version    Release: 0.1.0
    * @link       http://github.com/
    * @since      Class available since Release 0.1.0
 */
```

Is there any way to disable the indentation in between? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Late, but others might be searching as well (as was I for the last half hour). The solution is just as easy as it is stupid:

Use tabs not spaces in the definition of the snippet. (":set list" helps)